# ATM Project, logical errors

Tags: java, for-loop, logic, switch-statement

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ATM {
String names []= {"Nikhil", "Sam", "Raj", "Saron", "Abi", "Adi"};
int card[]={1806978,1244668,5769124,7658301,6571354,5155499};
int pin[]={4444, 3333, 2222, 1111, 6666, 7988};
int balance []={10000, 23345, 24673, 37532, 43637, 37356};
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int f,ch, z=0;
static int opt=0;

public static void main(String args []) {
    int enter=0;
    ATM k=new ATM();
    k.info();
    k.login(enter);
    int temp=k.login(enter);
    if(enter==1){
        k.menu(temp);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Wrong card no. or pincode");
    }

}


   void info(){
   Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd EEEEEEEEE',' yyyy ");
   SimpleDateFormat timeformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" hh:mm:ss a");
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("                  ****************************************************************       ");
   System.out.println("                  ***                         HSBC's  ATM                     ***         ");
   System.out.println("                  ****************************************************************       ");
   System.out.println("                  Date - "+ dateformatter.format(calender.getTime()));
   System.out.println("                  Time - "+timeformatter.format(calender.getTime()));
   System.out.println("                  ****************************************************************       ");
   System.out.println("");
   }

    int login(int enter){
   System.out.println("                  >> Enter card number - ");
   int card_no=s.nextInt();
   System.out.println("                  >> Enter pin number - ");
   int pin_no= s.nextInt();
   for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){

    if (card [i]==card_no && pin[i]==pin_no)
           enter=1;
           z=i;

    }
   return z;
   }
void menu (int temp){
    System.out.println("                  Welcome "+names[temp]);
    System.out.println("                  Your Card no: is " + card[temp]);
    System.out.println("                  ###############################################        ");
    System.out.println("                  >>> [1]. Cash Withdrawal ");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("                  >>> [2]. Fast Cash ");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("                  >>> [3]. Cash Deposit ");

     opt=s.nextInt();

    switch (opt){
    case 1:
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd'/'MM ");
        SimpleDateFormat timeformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm ");
        ATM k=new ATM();
        int ammount;
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  CASH WITHDRAWAL ");
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.print("                    Enter amount to withdraw - Rs.");
        ammount=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        System.out.println("                  Please wait while we process your request...");

 if (ammount>balance[z]){
        System.out.println("                  You do not have sufficient balance in your account.");
        k.menu(temp);
        for(z=1;z<=1000000000;z++)
        System.out.print("\f");
 }else if (ammount>25000){
        System.out.println("                  The daily limit for cash withdrawal is Rs.25000 .");
        k.menu(temp);
 }else{
        balance[z]=balance[z]-ammount;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("                  You have withdrawn Rs."+ammount+" from your account.");
        System.out.println("                  Please collect the cash.");
        System.out.println("                  Current Balance - Rs."+balance[z]);
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
       }
        break; 
    case 2:
        int fast[]={100,500,1000,5000};
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  FAST CASH WITHDRAWAL ");
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  Please select a desired amount.");
        System.out.println("                  (1) Rs. 100 ");
        System.out.println("                  (2) Rs. 500 ");
        System.out.println("                  (3) Rs. 1000 ");
        System.out.println("                  (4) Rs. 5000 ");
        System.out.print("                     Your choice ? ");
        ch=s.nextInt();
        if (fast[ch-1]>balance[z])
        {
        System.out.println("                  You do not have sufficient balance in your account.");
        }else{
            switch(ch)
            {
            case 1:
            balance[z]=balance[z]-fast[ch-1];
            break;
            case 2:
            balance[z]=balance[z]-fast[ch-1];
            break;
            case 3:
            balance[z]=balance[z]-fast[ch-1];
            break;
            case 4:
            balance[z]=balance[z]-fast[ch-1];
            break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("                  You have withdrawn Rs. "+fast[ch-1]+" from your account.");
        System.out.println("                  Please collect the cash.");
        System.out.println("                  Current Balance - Rs."+balance[z]);
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  CASH DEPOSIT ");
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.print("                  Enter amount to deposit - Rs.");
        int deposite =s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        System.out.println("                  Please wait while we process your request...");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("                  You have deposited Rs."+deposite+" to your account.");
        System.out.println("                  The amount will be credited shortly.");
        System.out.println("                  Current Balance - Rs."+balance[z]+" + Rs."+deposite);
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  BALANCE ENQUIRY ");
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  Account Number - "+card[z]);
        System.out.println("                  Available Balance - Rs."+balance[z]);
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        System.out.println("                  Please collect the reciept...");
  }
}
}
```

No matter what I enter as the the pin number or card number (even if it is correct) I get the message "Wrong card no. or pincode" And also it asks me for the card number and pin number twice. Any suggestions on improving the code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) `int enter=0;
 ..
    if(enter==1){`  I can see nowhere in the statements between those two, where the value of `enter` ever changes.  Why do you expect it to go into the `else`?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues here:

1. You are not changing `int enter=0;` value of this `enter` no where so it will be always 0 and your `if` condition will be always false.
2. Per you code flow I assume you are returning `1` or `0` like that from `k.login(enter);` method.
3. You are assigning that value to `int temp=k.login(enter);` but you are comparing with `enter` which is logically wrong, you need to compare it with `temp`.

Also show your code for `login`method, based on that I will revise the answer.

Comment: I'm not too sure as to what exactly I have to change in the main function regarding to the `enter` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the for loop in the login method the enter value you are passing is the problem.
 The enter value set in the login method is set to the local value so enter is always 0. Please check and rectify it should work fine